# Can Image3D be setup to make any voxel with an RGB element >1 or <0 black, or better yet clear?

Tags: graphics3d

I'm working with ~ 10^8 voxels which can have RGB values outside of 0 - 1.  Currently I go through nested For statements with a bunch of || tests.  It would be great to set such voxels to {0,0,0} within Image3D.  Better yet would be to turn the voxel transparent.

Here is a small example that obviously doesn't use all possible combinations of out of range elements:

```
test = {{{1.5, 1, 1}, {-1.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}, {-1.5, 0, 0}}, {{1.5,
      1, 1}, {-1.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}, {-1.5, 0, 0}}};

Image3D[test]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R,G,B values should be between 0 and 1. MMA will simply clip you values. E.g, the first voxel {1.5,1,1} will be clipped to {1,1,1} and therefore displayed as "white", what makes it invisible on a white background.

```
test = {{{{1.5, 1, 1}, {-1.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}, {-1.5, 0, 
      0}}, {{1.5, 1, 1}, {-1.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}, {-1.5, 0, 0}}}};
Image3D[test]
```

[image]

To get the full color palette, you must rescale your data, using e.g. `Rescale`:

```
test = {{{{1.5, 1, 1}, {-1.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}, {-1.5, 0, 
      0}}, {{1.5, 1, 1}, {-1.5, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}, {-1.5, 0, 0}}}};
test = Rescale[test, {-1.5, 1.5}]
Image3D[test]
```

[image]

However, if we want voxel with invalid colors to be invisible, we can add an  alpha channel and set it to 0 and use `ColorSpace -> "RGB"`. To demonstrate this we also need to change the data:

```
test = {{{{0, 1, 1}, {-1.5, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
      1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}, {-1.5, 0, 0}}}};
test = Map[Append[#, If[(0 <= Min[#]) && (Max[#] <= 1), 1, 0.]] &, 
  test, {3}]
Image3D[test, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

[image]

Comment: When all three RGB values are between 0 and 1, I keep those values.  If any RGB value is outside of 0 -to 1, I currently set to black.  I am basically setting a window, so rescaling is not an option for me.  Like I mentioned in the question, black is OK, but invoking an alpha channel to set the voxel as transparent is even better.  To do that, my current code uses nested For statements with inequalities and Or.  It takes 10 minutes on 512 x 512 x 512 x 3.  Maybe, I am stuck with it.

Comment: I added this to my answer.

Comment: That's great.  Now I need to figure out how to replace the RGB palette with a custom palette, but that's another question if need be.